# How to show XML parsed images by using Tap gestures in iphone?

Tags: iphone

I am making an App in which i am parsing an **XML** and storing the url of images in an array.
 Now i have to show all that images on next View Controller using **Tap Gestures** and when i **click** on images i have some **action** to perform. So please can anyone help me regarding that?
  I can provide the code what i have written if anyone want or tell me some tutorial as i am not able to get it from developer sites.

Comment: Any **tutorial** for doing my Task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Load your images into UIImage objects like so:

```
UIImage *imageFromUrl = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:url]];
```

Then, place them into UIImageView objects wherever you need them. The next thing you should do is add a TapGestureRecognizer:

```
UIImageView *imgView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:imageFromUrl];
UITapGestureRecognizer *tgr = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(action)];
[imgView addGestureRecognizer:tgr];
[tgr release];
//Do the rest of your operations here, don't forget to release the UIImageView
```

And that's it. Do whatever you need in the "action" method that will get called on your ViewController

Comment: So what i understand is that we are adding imageViews into Tap Gesture Recognizer and when ever we click on them the selector method will invoke..??

Comment: Yes, only we are actually adding the gesture recognizer to the image view, not vice versa.

Comment: Thanks a ton... a small more favour i need is that, do you have any sample code for that in which you have parsed some XML for having some image url stored in an array and then giving that url to image views dynamically.. :D

Comment: I don't have an example, sorry. All you have to do is load the data (preferably in an asynchronous method), using the UIImage initWithContentsOfFile method, and the file should be an NSURL fetched by fileURLWithPath

Answer (score 0):

For that you have to use TapDetactingimgView.
In that view you get scroll,single tap & double tap event.By that you can scroll image & able to tap on that image.

for that Visit : https://bitbucket.org/billgarrison/panzoomimagedemo/src/34671df61417/Classes/TapDetectingImageView.m